# Spring boot: apply @Configuration to certain package only

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, setcookie

I am using `@Configuration` to config cookies, while in my project there is 2 packages and I only want to apply the config to one of the package.
Are there any ways to set the target package for `@Configuration`?

package structure:
--app
----packageA
------MyConfigClass.java
----packageB

```
@EnableJdbcHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 1800)
@Configuration
public class MyConfigClass extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Bean
    public CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
        // I want the follow cookie config only apply to packageA
        DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
        serializer.setCookieName("myCookieName");
        serializer.setCookiePath("/somePath/");
        return serializer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you can use `@ComponentScan` to specify which packages to scan for and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` with the exclude options to omit the classes that you want to omit. You have to use this in your main application class.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { Class1.class,
        Class2.class,
        Class3.class }, 
excludeName = {"mypackage.classname"}))
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "mypackage" })
public class MyApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also provide the classes that you want to exclude in your configuration file.

```
# AUTO-CONFIGURATION
spring.autoconfigure.exclude= # Auto-configuration classes to exclude.
```

Comment: exclude applies only to Auto-Configuration for the record.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with @ComponentScan("packageA")

check http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html

Comment: I have added but the cookie is still returned... quiet sure I set the @ComponentScan correctly

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot, your main class annotated with `@SpringBootApplicatio` will already include `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` with their default attributes, so all your classes will be auto scanned. Using `exclude` in `@SpringBootApplication` will only exclude classes, but if you have lots of classes in your package, the code will look nasty.

In your case, the easiest way is to move your main Spring Boot application entry class into the package you want to be configured and auto scanned:

----packageA

------app

------MyConfigClass.java

----packageB

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go fine-grained like this, I wouldn't use component scan at all. `@SpringBootApplication` is a shortcut for three things:

1. Enable auto-configuration
2. Enable component scan in the package where the spring boot app resides (including sub packages)
3. Make sure the spring boot application itself is a configuration (so that you can contribute extra beans, import configurations, etc

If you want a Spring Boot application that only looks for configuration in a certain places, I'd do something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import(MyConfigClass.class)
public class MySpringBootApp { ... }
```

IMO, it is much more clear to include what you want in such scenario rather than having scanning with excludes. Perhaps you may want to restructure your app so you don't have to do this in the first place? Using profile is one option so that those unwanted configurations only applies when a profile is enabled.