# Spring Boot 1.5.4: exclude configuration class in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-test

I have a Spring Boot project, version 1.5.4, with a MongoDb configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

@Value("${spring.data.mongo.client.uri:mongodb://localhost:27017/database}")
private String mongoURI;

@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoFactory() throws UnknownHostException{
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClientURI(mongoURI));
}

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws UnknownHostException, MongoException{
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoFactory());
}
}
```

In my integration test i want use *Embedded Mongo* (https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo).

The problem is that the MongoDb configuration class start before the initialitation of Embedded mongo and try to connect to the database, so my test fail. If i remove the *MongoConfig* class, all test work well.

How can i exclude it only in my test execution?

Comment: I know this is not what your question is about, but take a look at testContainers : https://www.testcontainers.org/ it is the solution i use for my test (mainly integration testing) , a tiny tutorial here : https://areguig.github.io/test-springboot-apps-using-testContainers-and-spock/

Answer (score 2):

Exclude the MongoDB autoconfiguration by using below annotation over your test class.

**@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})**

Then in the same path as your test class create a configuration class and define your mongo bean over there. This will get picked up during application start up

```
**@Configuration
public class MockConfigurations {
@Bean
@Primary
public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() {
//define your bean
return mongoTemplate;
}
}**
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the answers here. It has two ways of excluding configurations.

[Spring boot: apply @Configuration to certain package only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103043/spring-boot-apply-configuration-to-certain-package-only/44258129#44258129)

**Update 1:**

Alternatively, the most efficient way that I can think of is to use Spring profiles and load the profile for the tests

Define your TestConfiguration class and import it your test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Import(MyTestConfiguration.class)
public class MyTests {

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() {
        ...
    }

}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config

**Update 2:** 
For EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration please refer the detailed answers here.

[How do you configure Embedded MongDB for integration testing in a Spring Boot application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568351/how-do-you-configure-embedded-mongdb-for-integration-testing-in-a-spring-boot-ap)

Comment: I don't want change my main Application class just for the unit test.

Comment: @Import(MyTestsConfiguration.class) is good solution, but i found a system that just avoid load useless class for my test.

Comment: The proble is that i don't know how to be my *MyTestsConfiguration.class*, becouse i want activate the *EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class*

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this configuration on my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ComponentScan({"it.app.server.dal","it.app.server.listener"})
@DataMongoTest() //mongoDB
public class ListenerTests {
   ...
}
```

The annotation *@DataMongoTest()* load my Embbedded MongoDb and with *@ComponentScan* i can just load the services and repositories wich i need in my test.

Comment: This solution doesn't work  if i want test a Controller that access to  mongodb.